# Eaton CHSPT2ULTRA installation location?

Tags: electrical-panel

My Eaton CHSPT2ULTRA is connected to the last breaker (bottom right) in my panel. It seems like it should be the first breaker (upper left) so that it would be in between the main and the rest if the circuit breakers. Is my current installation correct?

Comment: I think it is OK to install an Eaton CHSP2ULTRA far down in the panel. It does not have to be installed in a "blocking position" between the main breaker and the branch breakers. Without having an expert understanding of the matter I believe the wavelength of a spike is long compared to the lengths of couductor in the panel so I think a spike would develop almost simultaneously at all points in the panel. The surge protector shorts it to ground and protects branch circuits upstream and well as downstream. What size 2-pole circuit breaker is the surge protector connected through?

Answer (score 3):

According to the installation instructions, the important factors are breaker size, and having short and straight connections to the breaker. There is no note about putting the surge suppressor close to the main breaker, and in fact the picture in the instructions shows it installed in the middle of the panel. While there may be a small advantage to placing the surge suppressor closer to the main breaker, the bus is capable of carrying far more energy than the suppressor can sink. Without doing the engineering work, this leads me to suspect strongly that in practice there is no significance to where it is placed on the bus. Focus instead on short wires and straight runs.